# Travel Insurance for Italy tourist visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy

I'm applying for an Italian tourist visa in Japan soon (foreign resident in japan, need visa for travel). And the document checklist mentions that I need to have a travel insurance *issued by a company based in Italy or Japan*.

Despite searching for a while I haven't been able to find one. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does "issued by" mean the broker (the agent who sells it to you) or the underwriter (the company taking the insurance risk)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure, there isn't any additional information. I'd guess broker(?)

Comment: You should be able to obtain travel insurance by visiting any travel agent. In my country, supermarkets sell it too.

Comment: If it means the underwriter: I have had (UK) car insurance underwritten by a Gibraltar insurer and by a Denmark insurer. I now accept quotes only from UK registered insurers, and the broker can tell me that information.

Comment: You need travel health insurance as it is an entry requirement for the Schengen area - check out your local insurance company, many of them know this specific packages as "Schengen insurance"

Comment: Have you tried googling for *assicurazione viaggio* or 旅行保険 ? You will probably need help from Google Translate if you don't speak those languages.